# django rest_framework serializer parameter

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using django rest_framework to provide jsGrid json data.

As the rest_framwork example, I create a object fit the jsGrid format

```
class jsGridResp(object):
def __init__(self, data, itemsCount):
    self.data = data
    self.itemsCount = itemsCount
```

and the class based view, create a get function

```
class RateListViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
"""
API endpoint that allows user to be viewed or edited
"""
queryset = RateList.objects.all().order_by('-create_date')
serializer_class = RateListSerializer

def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    obj = queryset.get(pk=self.request.POST["id"])
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj

def get(self, request, format=None):
    pageIndex = request.GET.get('pageIndex')
    pageSize = request.GET.get('pageSize')

    sortField = request.GET.get('sortField', 'id')
    sortOrder = request.GET.get('sortOrder', 'asc')
    sortOrder = "" if sortOrder == "asc" else "-"

    rows = RateList.objects.all().order_by("{}{}".format(sortOrder, sortField))
    itemsCount = rows.count()

    paginator = Paginator(rows, pageSize)
    try:
        rows = paginator.page(pageIndex)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        rows = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        rows = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    result = jsGridResp(data=rows, itemsCount=itemsCount)
    serializer = RateListGetSerializer(result)

    json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

    return Response(json)
```

then I create two serializer to serialize the data

```
class RateListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = RateList
    fields = ('id', 'rate_code', 'hr01', 'hr02', 'hr03', 'hr04', 'hr05', 'hr06',
              'hr07', 'hr08', 'hr09', 'hr10', 'hr11', 'hr12', 'hr13', 'hr14',
              'hr15', 'note', 'create_date', 'update_date')
    read_only_fields = ('create_date', 'update_date')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        result = instance.update(id=instance.id, **validated_data)
        return result

    def destroy(self, instace, validated_data):
        return "{seccuess: true}"

class RateListGetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    itemsCount = serializers.IntegerField()
    data = RateListSerializer(many=True)
```

but I have many model need to do like these.
can I use just one serializer to serialize all model.
I want to create a jsGridGetSerializer can pass in a model parameter, so I don't need to create many simple serialzer to do the same thing.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want a generic serializer which accepts a Model variable as a parameter in its Meta class.

One way to do this is to pass in the model name as a url keyword argument, then catching it in views.py. Then you can override the Meta model via overriding the get_serializer_class:

**serializers.py**

```
class GenericSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = None
```

**views.py**

```
class GenericViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     def get_queryset(self):
         model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return model.objects.all()           

     def get_serializer_class(self):
         GenericSerializer.Meta.model = self.kwargs.get('model')
         return GenericSerializer
```